# Unable to access elements such as location or the description of the first time accessed Calendar event

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I am trying to develop a Marketplace Add-On, specifically for calendar. With the addon, I want to manipulate the location of the event currently being worked on, but it does not work if the event is a freshly created one. The code works for pre-existing events though. Is there any way we can achieve this functionality for new events?

The run time error when I run the code is as follows:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'setDescription')
```

The code I have used to insert into the description is as follows:

```
    var calendarId = e.calendar.calendarId;
    var eventId = e.calendar.id;
    var textToInsert = 'Text to populate description of the event'; 

    var event = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId).getEventById(eventId);

    event.setDescription(textToInsert);
```

Note: The above snippet is a part of the function the addon executes. When used on a pre-existing calendar event, it works well, but when the code is made to run on a new event, the above error is encountered.

Comment: Debugging question: What are the values returned for `calendarId` and `eventId`?